# WCF crashes after sending EF object with it's references

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I have database with several tables, including:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Exam]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY identity, 
    [Author id] INT NULL, 
    ...
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Exam_Author] FOREIGN KEY ([Author id]) REFERENCES [User]([Id]), 
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY identity, 
    ...
)
```

I have `ADO.NET` generated model of my database.

```
public partial class Exam
{
    public Exam()
    {
        ...
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Author_id { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    ...
}

public partial class Exam
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Exam = new HashSet<Exam>();
        ...
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Exam> Exam { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I have also `GetExam` function in my `Wcf service`, which returns one exam from database.

```
public Exam GetExam()
{
    var context = new GDBDatabaseEntities();
    context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    var exams = context.Exam;
    var exam = exams.FirstOrDefault();
    return exam;
}
```

Disabling `ProxyCreationEnabled` was necessary to send `Exam` through `Wcf`.

Unfortunately above code returns me an exam with empty `User` field (`EF` generated this field automatically as a response for `FK_Exam_Author`)...

I've tried to load `User` attribute with `Include` function:

```
var exams = context.Exam.Include("User");
```

I've got following `Wcf`'s error:

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

Just before return from `Wcf` debugger shows that `Exam` object looks properly (has loaded `User` dependency).

I think it could be caused by fact, that loaded `User` has loaded his `Exam`s list, which has loaded `User`... (circular dependence).

I've exact the same problem with `User` - `Wcf` works for `User` with empty `Exams[]` property, but when I've loaded list of `User`'s Exams, `Wcf` has crashed...

**How can I properly load relationship and send it via `Wcf`?**

Additional question is how `Wcf` know how to serialize my objects (when I've used `LINQ to SQL` it generated classes with `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes, but `Entity Framework` just don't do it.

### UPDATE

It's the problem with circular dependences, because

```
public Exam GetExam()
{
    var context = new GDBDatabaseEntities();
    context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    var exams = context.Exam.Include("User");
    var exam = exams.FirstOrDefault();
    exam.User.Exam = null;
    return exam;
}
```

works.

Could anyone explain me why `Include` function is necessary for load 1-level dependences, which i need, but other dependences are loading for infinity? It's radiculous...

### UPDATE

According to the answers and [Yahoo's Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site first rule](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) I decided to create new object for every single `Page` in my `Windows 8 application`, which will reduce amount of sending data, number of requests and will let me avoid sending redundant data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having tried this several times, I quickly abandoned using EF objects as my data contracts. As you found, the circular dependency breaks the `DataContractSerializer` very quickly. Additionally, your database objects likely contain information that doesn't need to be sent across the wire to clients.

Instead, create similar DataContract objects to the EF generated ones for use with WCF (without the circular dependencies and other problems), and translate between the two. For example:

```
[DataContract]
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<Exam> Exams {get; set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class Exam
{
   [DataMember]
   public int Score {get; set;}
}
```

Then you just need a loader function like:

```
IEnumerable<Contracts.User> GetAllUsers()
{
   foreach (DB.User in context.Users)
   {
       Contracts.User wcfUser = new Contracts.User();
       wcfUser.Exams = new List<Contracts.Exam>();
       foreach (DB.Exam exam in wcfUser.Exams)
          wcfUser.Exams.Add(new Contracts.Exam() { Score = exam.Score };

       yield return wcfUser;
   }
}
```

Obviously this expands your code-base quite a bit, but avoids having your clients needing to know about your database objects, helps keep your network traffic down, and results in a better separation of concerns.

Hopefully that answers your question! Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: Creating additional classes for every table is impossible (it's quite big project). It's hard to believe that there's no native support for `WCF` in `EF`, because I've solved identical problem using `LINQ to SQL`, which is knonw as more crude.

Comment: I've seen that break as well (as you point out, they are very similar). As noted in my answer, it is definitely a lot of extra code, but it is also not a very good idea to send database objects (with all their context tracking, circular properties, etc) over a WCF connection. EF classes were never meant to be WCF data contracts. I haven't used it, but you may want to look into WCF data services, as it has some automatic hookup to database objects.

Comment: you're right, it is not a very good idea to send database objects over a WCF connection. See my update.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve the problem! Was there any additional information you were looking for from your update?