# Exposing Entity Framework data types over WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

Edit: I don't know how you guys do this, but this question is indeed a duplicate. See above.

at the moment what I have on my hands is a WCF service that exposes a few basic operations:

```
public interface IUniService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool IsUser(string userName);

    [OperationContract]
    User GetUserByUsername(string userName);
}
```

I also have an Entity Framework database running. 
Here's a bit of code that accesses the server.

```
public bool IsUser(string userName)
{
    using (UniDBEntities db = new UniDBEntities())
    {
        User a = new User();
        var user = db.Users.Where(p => p.UserName == userName).ToList();
        return (user.Count() != 0);
    }
}
```

But the question I have is, I want to expose via the WCF service, some of the classes that are currently in my Entity Framework. When I write a function like:

```
User GetUserById(int id)
```

when I return the result, it doesn't seem as though my client has any idea what the User class is. How do I expose my entities as Datamembers?

Comment: Please, please don't do this. EF classes were never meant to be used by WCF (the circular properties will break the serializer right away, and they have a whole bunch of junk you don't want to deal with). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674692/wcf-crashes-after-sending-ef-object-with-its-references/22674975#22674975

Comment: So you need some proxy classes/DTO's, then?  Well, that's... Awkward.

Comment: Anyway use `return db.Users.Any(p => p.UserName == userName)` instead of your query. It will generate the most efficient SQL.

Comment: To the edit, we are magic :) Actually we just read and answer a lot of questions, and remember enough that we can spot duplicates! If you are referring to the link I marked as a possible duplicate, I actually wrote the answer a few weeks ago :), and remembered it when reading this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can transparently disconnect EF objects from the db easily, however you can create a dto or poco and send that over the network. For reads is not a problem, you send read-only data, for writing to the db, either create method dedicated to updating data, or you can take the EF object, send and receive a copy, suitably wrapped as poco/dto, and then update it with the changes.

It's probably better though to model your middle tier differently to the db schema however, make ita domain model so there's not a 1 to 1 mapping between wcf methods and EF objects. Then you can make your wcf model more appropriate for the caller.

Look up the repository pattern as an example.